# Editing widgets in Kubuntu 16.04

Tags: kubuntu, kde, widgets

In Kubuntu 16.04 how to change the label and icon in a desktop widget, please?  I have found the .desktop files in usr/share/applications/kde4 and edited one of those but with no effect on the desktop widget.  (That used to be the way in 12.04.)

Answer (score 1):

**Plasma 5 qml widgets**

KDE start page - Development/Tutorials/Plasma5/QML2/GettingStarted: https://techbase.kde.org/Development/Tutorials/Plasma5/QML2/GettingStarted

Plasma 5 plasmoid widgets name, comment and the icon are saved to the metadata.desktop and matadata.json files:

[image]

The plasmoids are saved to the:

- System: /usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/
- User: $HOME/.local/share/plasma/plasmoids/

The user can edit the codes at the /usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/.. but the plasma updates will overwrite the edits.

A better way is to copy the plasmoid to the user home and rename the plasmoid.

Few examples from the KDE Forums:

- Kickoff-1: https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=131914
- Kickoff-2: https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=140979
- Digital clock: https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=134970
- Timer: https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=67&t=137743